# Store And Retrieve File Existed on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which consists of one root application (CMS) and another sub application called (RG) as virtual application like the screenshot taken from IIS below:

[image: IIS Image]

My problem is, from the CMS application I create some user file and store it in a folder called `UserFiles`. Then from my (RG) application, I want to retrieve that file back to my code and process it. It is an xml file.

The configuration for the `UserFiles` is like the following:

```
<add key="UserFiles" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CMS\UserFiles\" />
```

So far what I did in my sub project is like the following:

```
string serverPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserFiles"];
string filename = serverPath + usrId + "\\XmlFiles\\filename.xml";
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xdoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(filename);
```

but I got nothing, I don't know what am doing wrong,

**Note**: retrieving the file using the CMS application with the same method works for me but not for the other application.

Can anyone please direct me to the proper way to do it, or tell me what I am missing here?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you debugged and checked what you are getting for "filename" variable? Does the file exist in that path?

Comment: actually its my bad, i feel ashamed because when debugging i realized that i did exclude my partial view which display the file content. And your answer saved my day...thank you